# refreshApex not working in lwc datatable after update

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, refreshapex

I am using lwc datatable to get task records which are related to Account and Lead. Then i am using row action to display task details and update the task. Once i am updating the task, i am marking the task as "Completed" . Once i update the task , i want the lighting table to get refreshed and the record should get removed from datatable. I am currently unable to refresh  the record from  datatable.

Below is the pic ..

[image]

In this datatable `recordsToDisplay` is the variable which is holding the data for datatable.

Once i click save, i am marking the task as "Completed" and i am trying to remove the row once save is done.

In this i have a child component `c-paginator` which takes all the records queried and sends an event to parent with all the rowOffet and `recordsToDisplay` to be displayed.

Once i am clicking save, i am able to save it , but i am unable to remove the row from datatable

HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isLoaded}>
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Saving......" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
    <lightning-card title="">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item size=8 style="margin-left: 21px;">
                <template if:true={showTable}>
                    <c-paginator records={records} total-records={records.length} show-search-box="true"
                        onpaginatorchange={handlePaginatorChange}>
                    </c-paginator>
                </template>
                <lightning-datatable class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked" hide-checkbox-column
                    onheaderaction={handleHeaderAction} onrowaction={handleRowAction} key-field="Id"
                    data={recordsToDisplay} columns={columns} show-row-number-column row-number-offset={rowNumberOffset}
                    default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection} sorted-direction={sortDirection} sorted-by={sortedBy}
                    onsort={onHandleSort}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <lightning-layout-item size=3 style="margin-top: 34px;">
                <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
                    <lightning-tab label="Update Activity">
                        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                            <lightning-layout-item size=12>
                                <a href={recordPageUrl} target="_blank">View Activity</a>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item size=12 class="slds-m-top_small">
                                <lightning-input label="Subject" value={sub}></lightning-input>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item size=12 class="slds-m-top_small">
                                <template if:true={callTestlist.data}>
                                    <lightning-combobox name="Call Test" label="Call Test"
                                        value={value} options={callTestPicklist.data.values}
                                        onchange={handleChange}>
                                    </lightning-combobox>
                                </template>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item size=12 class="slds-m-top_small">
                                <lightning-input label="Follow Up on Next Call" value={followupcheck}
                                    type="checkbox" onchange={handleFollowUpChange} checked={followupcheck}>
                                </lightning-input>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item size=12 class="slds-m-top_small">
                                <lightning-textarea label="Notes" value={inputNoteValue} onchange={handleNoteChange}>
                                </lightning-textarea>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item size=12 class="slds-m-top_small">
                                <lightning-button onclick={handlesave} label="Save And Continue" variant="brand"
                                    style="float: right;">
                                </lightning-button>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </lightning-layout>
                    </lightning-tab>
                </lightning-tabset>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS to get Task

```
       connectedCallback() {
        alert('connected call back')
        this.getTaskRecords()
    }

    getTaskRecords() {
    getTasks()
        .then(result => {

            //const { data, error } = result;
            var data = result;
            this.recordsToDisplay = result
            if (data) {
                let recs = [];
                // var data = result.data;
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let task = {};
                    task.rowNumber = '' + (i + 1);
                    // task.comLink = '/' + data[i].Who.Id || '/' + data[i].AccountId;
                    if (data[i].Who.Id && data[i].Who.Id.startsWith('00Q')) {
                        task.obj = 'Lead'
                        task.comLink = '/' + data[i].Who.Id
                    }
                    if (data[i].AccountId) {
                        task.obj = 'Account'
                        task.comLink = '/' + data[i].AccountId
                    }
                    task.Company = data[i].Who.Company || data[i].Account.Name;
                    task.Name = data[i].Who.Name;
                    task.ph = 'tel:' + data[i].Who.Phone || 'tel:' + data[i].Account.Phone;
                    task.Phone = data[i].Who.Phone || data[i].Account.Phone;
                    task.Address = data[i].Who.City + ' ' + data[i].Who.Street + ' ' + data[i].Who.State + ' ' + data[i].Who.Country + ' ' + data[i].Who.Postalcode;
                    task.Industry = data[i].Who.Industry || data[i].Account.Industry;
                    task.CreatedDate = data[i].CreatedDate;
                    task.Status = data[i].Status;
                    task = Object.assign(task, data[i]);
                    recs.push(task);
                }
                this.ALL_TASKS = recs;
                this.records = recs;
                //if (this.template.querySelector("c-paginator")) {
                //     this.template.querySelector("c-paginator").setRecordsToDisplay();
                // }
                this.showTable = true;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
}

//Capture the event fired from the paginator component
handlePaginatorChange(event) {
    alert('handle-paginator')
    this.recordsToDisplay = event.detail;
    this.rowNumberOffset = this.recordsToDisplay[0].rowNumber - 1;
}

handleRowAction(event) {

    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    this.sub = row.Subject;
    this.recordPageUrl = '/' + row.Id;
    this.followupcheck = row.Scheduled_Follow_Up_on_Next_Call_Block__c;
    this.sub = row.Subject;
    this.inputNoteValue = row.Description
    //switch (actionName) {
    //    case 'View':
    this.showRowDetails(row);
    //       break;
    //default:
    //}
}

showRowDetails(row) {
    this.record = row;
    this.followupcheck = row.Scheduled_Follow_Up_on_Next_Call_Block__c;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
}


onHandleSort(event) {

    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const cloneData = [...this.recordsToDisplay];

    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    this.recordsToDisplay = cloneData;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = sortedBy;

}

sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {

    const key = primer
        ? function (x) {
            return primer(x[field]);
        }
        : function (x) {
            return x[field];
        };

    return function (a, b) {
        a = key(a);
        b = key(b);
        return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    };

}

handleChange(event) {
    this.value = event.detail.value;
}
@track inputNoteValue;
handleNoteChange(event) {
    this.inputNoteValue = event.target.value
}
@track followupcheck;
handleFollowUpChange(e) {
    this.followupcheck = e.target.checked;
    console.log(this.followupcheck)
}

handlesave(event) {
    this.isLoaded = true;
    console.log(this.followupcheck)
    var task;
    var lead;
    task = {
        'sobjectType': 'Task',
        'Id': this.record.Id,
        'Status': 'Completed',
        'Subject': this.sub,
        'Description': this.inputNoteValue
    };

    lead = {
        'sobjectType': 'Lead',
        'Id': this.record.Who.Id,
        'Add_to_Call_Block__c': this.followupcheck
    }
    console.log(lead)
    console.log(task)

    saveRecords({ tsk: task, ld: lead })
        .then(result => {
            this.isLoaded = false;
            //this.contacts = result;
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            //refreshApex(this.wiredApexData)
            this.getTaskRecords()
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.isLoaded = false;
            this.error = error;
        });

}

handleHeaderAction(event) {
    // gives the selection header action name
    const actionName = event.detail.action.name;

    // gives selected column definition
    const colDef = event.detail.columnDefinition;

    // assigning colmuns to new variable
    let cols = this.columns;

    if (actionName !== undefined) {
        if (actionName === 'Lead') {
            this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task =>
                // console.log(_task.obj === actionName)
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task.obj === actionName)
            );
        } else if (actionName === 'Both') {
            this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS;
        } else if (actionName === 'Account') {
            this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task.obj === actionName)
        }

        if (colDef.label === 'Industry') {
            if (actionName !== 'All') {
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task[colDef.label] === actionName);
            } else if (actionName === 'All') {
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS;
            }
        }

        if (colDef.label === 'Date Added') {

            if (actionName === 'Today') {
                let today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task.CreatedDate.substring(0, 10) === today)
            } else if (actionName === 'Last 7 days') {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
                let last7days = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task.CreatedDate.substring(0, 10) >= last7days)
            } else if (actionName === 'All') {
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS;
            } else if (actionName === 'Yesterday') {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
                let yesterday = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task.CreatedDate.substring(0, 10) >= yesterday)
            } else if (actionName === 'Tomorrow') {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                let tomorrow = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.ALL_TASKS.filter(_task => _task.CreatedDate.substring(0, 10) === tomorrow)
            }

        }
    }

    cols.find(col => col.label === colDef.label).actions.forEach(action => action.checked = action.name === actionName);
    this.columns = [...cols];
}
```

paginatorjs -

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

const DELAY = 300;
const recordsPerPage = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100];
const pageNumber = 1;
const showIt = 'visibility:visible';
const hideIt = 'visibility:hidden'; //visibility keeps the component space, but display:none doesn't
export default class Paginator extends LightningElement {
    @api showSearchBox = false; //Show/hide search box; valid values are true/false
    @api showPagination; //Show/hide pagination; valid values are true/false
    @api pageSizeOptions = recordsPerPage; //Page size options; valid values are array of integers
    @api totalRecords; //Total no.of records; valid type is Integer
    @api records; //All records available in the data table; valid type is Array 
    @track pageSize; //No.of records to be displayed per page
    @track totalPages; //Total no.of pages
    @track pageNumber = pageNumber; //Page number
    @track searchKey; //Search Input
    @track controlPagination = showIt;
    @track controlPrevious = hideIt; //Controls the visibility of Previous page button
    @track controlNext = showIt; //Controls the visibility of Next page button
    recordsToDisplay = []; //Records to be displayed on the page

    //Called after the component finishes inserting to DOM
    connectedCallback() {
        if (this.pageSizeOptions && this.pageSizeOptions.length > 0)
            this.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];
        else {
            this.pageSize = this.totalRecords;
            this.showPagination = false;
        }
        this.controlPagination = this.showPagination === false ? hideIt : showIt;
        this.setRecordsToDisplay();
    }

    handleRecordsPerPage(event) {
        this.pageSize = event.target.value;
        this.setRecordsToDisplay();
    }
    handlePageNumberChange(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.pageNumber = event.target.value;
            this.setRecordsToDisplay();
        }
    }
    previousPage() {
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber - 1;
        this.setRecordsToDisplay();
    }
    nextPage() {
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
        this.setRecordsToDisplay();
    }
    @api setRecordsToDisplay() {
        this.recordsToDisplay = [];
        if (!this.pageSize)
            this.pageSize = this.totalRecords;

        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.pageSize);

        this.setPaginationControls();

        for (let i = (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.pageSize; i < this.pageNumber * this.pageSize; i++) {
            if (i === this.totalRecords) break;
            this.recordsToDisplay.push(this.records[i]);
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('paginatorchange', { detail: this.recordsToDisplay })); //Send records to display on table to the parent component
    }
    setPaginationControls() {
        //Control Pre/Next buttons visibility by Total pages
        if (this.totalPages === 1) {
            this.controlPrevious = hideIt;
            this.controlNext = hideIt;
        } else if (this.totalPages > 1) {
            this.controlPrevious = showIt;
            this.controlNext = showIt;
        }
        //Control Pre/Next buttons visibility by Page number
        if (this.pageNumber <= 1) {
            this.pageNumber = 1;
            this.controlPrevious = hideIt;
        } else if (this.pageNumber >= this.totalPages) {
            this.pageNumber = this.totalPages;
            this.controlNext = hideIt;
        }
        //Control Pre/Next buttons visibility by Pagination visibility
        if (this.controlPagination === hideIt) {
            this.controlPrevious = hideIt;
            this.controlNext = hideIt;
        }
    }
    handleKeyChange(event) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
        const searchKey = event.target.value;
        if (searchKey) {
            this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.controlPagination = hideIt;
                this.setPaginationControls();

                this.searchKey = searchKey;
                //Use other field name here in place of 'Name' field if you want to search by other field
                //this.recordsToDisplay = this.records.filter(rec => rec.includes(searchKey));
                //Search with any column value (Updated as per the feedback)
                this.recordsToDisplay = this.records.filter(rec => JSON.stringify(rec).includes(searchKey));
                if (Array.isArray(this.recordsToDisplay) && this.recordsToDisplay.length > 0)
                    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('paginatorchange', { detail: this.recordsToDisplay })); //Send records to display on table to the parent component
            }, DELAY);
        } else {
            this.controlPagination = showIt;
            this.setRecordsToDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to call the method imperatively. @wire method holds the data in cache which is sometime not clear by refresh apex.

Comment: `refreshApex` is specifically designed to clear the cache. However, if you are always clearing the cache then imperative Apex is the way to go - make sure you remove the `cacheable = true` on the aura enabled method too.

Comment: Hi Phil .. I tried with imperative.. still not able to make it work.. this.wiredApexData --> this track variable is always holding the old values..

Comment: With imperative you don't need to keep the wiredApexData. Did you remember to remove the cacheable setting on the AuraEnabled method too?

Comment: Hi Phil.. i have removed the cacheable setting and wiredApexData. its not working

Comment: you're data displaying in datatable is in `recordsToDisplay` which is only updated when handling a paginator change. Any reason you're not updating this within the wire to get refreshed data? The wire only takes the returned data into your `records` variable which is only used in your `c-paginator` above the datatable.

Comment: correct Kris.. c-paginator sends an event which fills up recordsToDisplay variable.. What should i do  Kris.. Can you please suggest..

Comment: Have you confirmed the event is sent after a `refreshapex`? Some well-placed `console.log` with regards to the wire and your event being sent/handled would provide necessary debugging info. We have no visibility into the `c-paginator` logic so I can't provide a comment on whether it is handling it or not.

Comment: Hi Kris.. Since yesterday .. i have changed my code from wire to imperative.. i have updated my entire code above.. both paginator js and main js.. can u have a look..

Comment: Even with all the code, it's much more helpful if you could [edit] your question and provide clear steps you've taken with regards to the work you've done to debug and what you've noted. Ex. Confirming what gets called when you do `refreshApex` , what the data looks like returned, checking that the data in the underlying database is truly being updated successfully, etc.

Comment: Hi Kris.. i have updated the post..